# Multiple grouped dropdown buttons in a row with Twitter Bootstrap 2.x

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-2, buttongroup

It there an easy way to get button [dropdowns](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns) grouped like [button-groups](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups) with Twitter Bootstrap?

**This code**

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
<div class="btn-group">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            January
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="active">January</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">February</a></li>
            <!-- ... -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            2012
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" rel="2012" class="active">2012</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="2011">2011</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="2010">2010</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="2009">2009</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Result**

[image: Button group]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solution is place dropdown button into grouped button.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/RayZ/CgBTn/49/

```
    <div class="btn-group"> <!-- group container for buttons merging -->
        <div class="btn btn-group">  <!-- button and dropdown group in one -->
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                One 
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-group">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                Two
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Some CSS tweaks:

```
.btn-group.btn {   border: 0;   padding: 0; }
.btn-group.btn > .btn { border-radius: 0 }
.btn-group.btn > .dropdown-menu {  text-align: left; }
.btn-group.btn:first-child > .btn {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
          border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.btn-group.btn:last-child > .btn {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
          border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

​

Comment: Ok, got it! Replaced buttons with divs, and all things goes fine for me in FF.