# Multiple buttons in Twitter Bootstrap show the same dropdown - why?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put together a little dropdown menu with Bootstrap. I put up a sample on JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4MVnn/4/).

The idea would be to have each button trigger a different dropdown list, so that clicking on File gives you a dropdown containing New and Close, clicking on Edit gives you a dropdown containing Copy, Paste and Undo and so on.

However, I get the same dropdown for all buttons. I surely must have done something wrong.

I also had a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RayZ/CgBTn/), linked to by [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763176/multiple-grouped-dropdown-buttons-in-a-row-with-twitter-bootstrap), but it doesn't seem to work - no dropdown shows at all when clicking.

Any suggestion?

Here is a copy of the HTML:

```
<div id="mainMenubar" class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn" href="#" onclick="alert('Hello!');">Menu</button>
    <button href="#" class="btn dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">File</button>
    <ul id="fileMenuSelector" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Close</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button href="#" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Edit</button>
    <ul id="editMenuSelector" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Copy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Paste</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Undo</a></li>                   
    </ul>
    <button href="#" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Debug</button>
    <ul id="debugMenuSelector" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Some Debug</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Show XML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Show Log</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shut down the lot</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use links (anchors) inside the buttons to trigger the dropdowns instead...

```
       <button class="btn btn-group">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                File 
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Close</a></li>
            </ul>
        </button>
```

### [Here's a working demo](http://bootply.com/60960)

EDIT: Here's an *alternate* version inside a .btn-toolbar so that each dropdown is inside its own btn-group. This works in **FireFox**: **http://bootply.com/61019**

Comment: I had a look at your Bootply but it looks like the dropdown menus don't appear when clicking on the buttons.

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox 20.0.1 and IE 10. It works in Chrome, but that's no help as the target is expected to be IE.

Comment: Here is a version that works on FF and Chrome (I'm not able to test IE 10): http://bootply.com/61019 I put it inside a customized .btn-toolbar.

Comment: It works! It also works under IE10, as well as IE8, and that's good for those stuck working with older versions of IE. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
<div id="mainMenubar">
  <button class="btn" href="#" onclick="alert('Hello!');">Menu</button>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button href="#" class="btn dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">File</button>
    <ul id="fileMenuSelector" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Close</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button href="#" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Edit</button>
    <ul id="editMenuSelector" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Copy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Paste</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Undo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button href="#" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Debug</button>
    <ul id="debugMenuSelector" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Some Debug</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Show XML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Show Log</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shut down the lot</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edited to add styling for the navbar as discussed below:

```
.navbar {
  display: table;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a {
  padding: 5px;
}

.navbar-inner {
  min-height: 0
}
```

Comment: Indeed it does, but is there a way to group the buttons together as if they are in the same button group?

Comment: I'm unsure of what you're asking.  Can you point to an example?

Comment: Have a look at my JSFiddle. The drop down menu don't work as I intended, but the buttons are grouped together, because they are in the same btn-group. I was hoping to group them together like that, with no margin, but get the different dropdowns to work. To add more detail: I copied and pasted your code in a jsfiddle but it looks as if the buttons are spaced out, with quite  a bit of white space between them.

Comment: @Skelly's solution works.  You might also want to consider a navbar.  On the [Components Page](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html) take a look at `Pills with dropdowns` and `Basic navbar` (which can also be configured with dropdowns).

Comment: I'll give a try to @Skelly's solution. I used to have a full featured navbar but the design has changed and I had to build something that takes little horizontal space.

Comment: Is there a way to have a small navbar, taking less space vertically and using only a given number of pixels horizontally?

Comment: Sure... all you need to do is add some custom styling.  I edited my answer with what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is like nearly 4 years old but i stumble across the same problem. ZimSystem have the correct answer but you mentioned that there is still some white spaces left when you copy and paste his code. Thats because his code isnt wrap inside a correct css style.

The fact that is nice when dropdown and buttons style doesn't look messy when put it in the same group, but anoying thing is the dropdown doesnt work properly.

Anyway here is a working code example without the use of modifying and bootstrap.css

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**dropdown-toggle** class is put on the last button because it will put a border radius at the end making it look neat and finished.

I hope this will help someone else.